# Ubuntu shell script to open multiple tabs , load bashrc file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

hi i am doing following steps manually

1. open terminal (loads ~/.bashrc)
2. open 6 tabs
3. set titles for each tab
4. source libray files `source test.sh tab1` command with different parameter in each tab.
5. run Test (`./run.sh`)

i tried to automate the above steps uing shell script using gnome-terminal (using following link) , 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/500357/opening-multiple-terminal-tabs-and-running-command
the tabs are opening but titles are not saving it is resetting and the command `source ~/test.sh tab1`  giving error "No such file or directory"

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /media/Extra/Project

tab=" --tab-with-profile=Default"
options=(--tab --title=Terminal)

cmds[1]="'source ~/test_1.sh; ./run.sh'"
titles[1]="test_1"

cmds[2]="'source ~/test_2.sh; ./run.sh'"
titles[2]="test_2"


cmds[3]="'source ~/test_3.sh; ./run.sh'"
titles[3]="test_3"

cmds[4]="'source ~/test_4.sh; ./run.sh'"
titles[4]="test_4"

cmds[5]="'source ~/test_5.sh; ./run.sh'"
titles[5]="test_5"

cmds[6]="'source ~/test_6.sh; ./run.sh'"
titles[6]="test_6"

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
    options+=($tab --title="${titles[i]}"  -e "bash -ic \"${cmds[i]} ; bash\"" )     
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"

exit 0
```

Comment: The error message vaguely suggests that you are using `sh` instead of `bash` and hence getting an error message when you use a bashism. Anyway, show us your script.

Comment: updated the question with the script

Comment: Including the precise error message would also have been helpful but I think I have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes inside the double quotes are causing the entire string to be interpreted as the name of a command, whitespace and all, which of course does not work.  Remove them and your script should work (albeit still somewhat awkwardly).

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Anyway, if the script really is quite this repetitive, just factor everything inside the loop and get rid of the arrays completely.

Comment: Thanks working fine if we "remove single quotes inside the double quotes" and  "use full path source /full/path/test.sh tab1." as candymanuu mentioned.

Comment: You don't really need a full path but you cannot use `~/` inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

use full path

```
source /full/path/test.sh tab1
```

and show us you script like tripleee said